# How to debug using GDB with a program that uses shell script?

Tags: shell, debugging, gdb, sh

I have an extensive fortan/C parallel code (uses OpenMPI 4.2) and to run it I use a shell script (run.sh file). Here is how the inside of the run.sh file looks like:

```
module load cmake/3.3.2
module load gcc/7.4.0
module load openmpi-4.0.1-2

NPROCS=48

EXE=~/build/bin/cfd.exe 

date
srun -n $NPROCS $EXE
date
```

Here is the batch script I use to submit a job

```
 sbatch -N 1 -n 48 -p *cluster_name* -t 1:00:00 ./run.sh
```

I'm trying to debug the code using GDB but not sure how to get it working. Currently, I initialize GDB from command line by typing gdb along with the path to my executable and then type run but it starts the serial version of code and fails after first few lines. Can someone please help to attach the gdb process?

Comment: I have no knowledge about parallel programs, but do you search something like https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Attach.html  ?